# How to verify the token and get score using react-google-recaptcha-v3?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

I'm using the library [react-google-recaptcha-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha-v3) in order to integrate reCAPTCHA v3 into my React application, which also uses Next.

There's the following example in the README introducing users to the `useGoogleReCaptcha` hook:

```
import {
  GoogleReCaptchaProvider,
  useGoogleReCaptcha
} from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3';

const YourReCaptchaComponent  = () => {
  const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha();
  const token = executeRecaptcha("login_page");

  return (...)
}

ReactDom.render(
  <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey="[Your recaptcha key]">
    <YourReCaptchaComponent />
  </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I'm confused how I am supposed to use `const token = executeRecaptcha("login_page")`. I don't currently understand how developers should use this `token`. Isn't there a "score" associated with this token, whereby potential bots will be disallowed from using the page?

How do I verify this token and work with it? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The score is associated with the token but that'll be produced when you're doing the actual backend verification request with the token itself. [Step 3 of this paragraph](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge)

In a gist:

- Setup the front-end reCaptcha v3 like you've done and obtain the token
- Setup a backend validation service in a language of your choice for the [verification](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) with your secret key

[Here's a node example with promises](https://github.com/codeep/react-recaptcha-google#4-implement-code-server-side-to-validate-the-response) . You may just aswell simply make use [of fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```
    import * as request from 'request'; // from "web-request": "^1.0.7",
    
    async check(recaptchaResponse: string, remoteAddress: string): Promise<boolean> {
     const secretKey = "";
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
          const verificationUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' + secretKey + '&response=' + recaptchaResponse + '&remoteip=' + remoteAddress;
          request(verificationUrl
            , function(error, response, body) {
              if (error) {
                return reject(false);
              }
              if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                return reject(false);
              }
    
              body = JSON.parse(body);
              const passCaptcha = !(body.success !== undefined && !body.success);
              resolve(passCaptcha);
            });
        });
      }
```

[Here's an express middleware to delegate the whole process](https://github.com/pdupavillon/express-recaptcha)

e.g.:

```
    app.post('/', function(req, res){
      recaptcha.verify(req, function(error, data){
        if (!req.recaptcha.error) {
          // success code
        } else {
          // error code
        }
      });
    });
```

- The response will then contain the score mentioned and based on that you can take the appropriate action that you wish to, e.g.:

```
    {
      "success": true,
    [...]
      "score": 0.9,
      "action": "examples/v3scores",
      "error-codes": []
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this help answer. I think I might be conceptually confused regarding "backend verification" and the subsequent actions users take based on the score. For instance, what action am I the developer meant to take if the score is low? Isn't this built into the new version of reCAPTCHA?

Comment: No, it's not built into it, the whole point is the lack of friction and you undertaking action upon reviewing and interpreting the score you're given.

The page has a few examples on what you may apply as remedy measures whenever you get tokens with lower scores within the different sections of your interactions: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#interpreting_the_score

So, it's up to your particular use case whether v3 is the right choice or not.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Given I'm using the package `react-google-recaptcha-v3`, I wonder if the action is set by the user via `executeRecaptcha(SOME_ACTION);`

Comment: regarding the `secret key`, is this key something that is only used in the back end and has nothing to do with front end? (e.g send secret token with request). If so, the only thing the front end needs is the `site-key`?

Answer (score 2):

I find node server implementations for verify your token and get score.

```
var express = require('express'),                       
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var SECRET_KEY = "<Your Key>";

// enable CORS using npm package
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// verify reCAPTCHA response
app.post('/verify', (req, res) => {
  var VERIFY_URL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${SECRET_KEY}&response=${req.body['g-recaptcha-response']}`;
  return fetch(VERIFY_URL, { method: 'POST' })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => res.send(json));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on: ' + port);
});
```

credits:
https://github.com/cluemediator/verify-recaptcha-v3-nodejs

Check these articles for more informations -
backend implementation - https://www.cluemediator.com/how-to-verify-google-recaptcha-v3-response

you can check frontend implementation either (there is server call) -
fronted implementation - https://www.cluemediator.com/how-to-implement-recaptcha-v3-in-react#cabatvrr